# What's the best word for saying that you... "follow a cause"?

Tags: word-choice

I want to write a sentence similar to "In favor of open-source technologies", but really don't know which word would be the best at the beginning.

I've thought about "Advocate of open-source technologies", but according to Google, *"Advocate: a person who publicly supports or recommends a particular cause or policy"*, so I think that wouldn't be a good one, as I understand it's more oriented to people defending open-source technologies at conferences, media or so.

What other choices do I have?

Comment: Are you looking for a _noun_?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Supporter; proponent; advocate.

> [Straker looks at his principal with cool skepticism; then turns to
>   the car whistling his favorite air]. Stop that aggravating noise. What
>   do you mean by it? [Straker calmly resumes the melody and finishes it.
>   Tanner politely hears it out before he again addresses Straker, this
>   time with elaborate seriousness]. Enry: I have ever been a warm **advocate** of > the spread of music among the masses; but I object to your obliging the company > whenever Miss Whitefield's name is mentioned.

G.B. Shaw. "Man and Superman."

Answer (score 6):

Consider **adherent**:

> someone who supports a particular belief, plan, political party etc

([Longman](http://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/adherent))

> For everyone else who professes to be an **open source adherent**, OSS is simply a marketing or sales tactic.

([www.ebizq.net](http://www.ebizq.net/topics/open_source/features/10321.html?page=2))

> I dislike Skype as much as **any open-source adherent**, but I can't very well insist that all my friends and colleagues with Macs and Windows stop using it, hence Skype will also be installed on my Linux systems for the foreseeable future.

([forums.fedoraforum.org](http://forums.fedoraforum.org/showpost.php?p=1325135&postcount=3))

Comment: I saw the title and instantly thought of this. My gut tells me this might answer the question better, it as seems like a more passive word (a criterion the OP seems to want) than any in the accepted answer. However, that might just be my own biased connotations at work!

Answer (score 3):

Consider *[devotee](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/devotee)*

> A person who is very interested in and enthusiastic about someone or something:
>   a devotee of classical music

Or perhaps *[aficionado](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/aficionado)*

> A person who is very knowledgeable and enthusiastic about an activity, subject, or pastime:
>   aficionados of the finest wines

*Oxford Dictionaries Online*

Answer (score 2):

*I **favour/support** open-source technologies.*

*Favour* - To regard with favour, look kindly upon; to be inclined to, have a liking or preference for; to approve. (OED)

Answer (score 1):

[Promote](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/promote) might work here. The exact phrasing depends on what you want to say next:

> To promote open-source technologies, our company presents ...

etc.

The linked [M-W] entry also suggests similar alternatives, such as *further* (verb), which may sound somewhat lofty.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on context, how about ***partisan***?

> partisan: a firm adherent to a party, faction, cause, or person; especially :  one exhibiting blind, prejudiced, and unreasoning allegiance [M-W](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/partisan)
>
> *Jarrett’s claim to fame is that he was a partisan of the cause of
> African Americans in the broad democratic tradition of Paul Robeson
> and W.E.B. DuBois.* [RomanticPoet Wordpress](https://romanticpoet.wordpress.com/tag/barbara-bowman-erikson-institute/)
>
> *Some will complain that Gopnik is, in the end, a partisan of the
> theory that Oswald acted alone. After raising the possibility that
> some faction in the Cold War national-security state might have
> decided to kill the president, Gopnik refuses the poisoned chalice of
> conspiracy and imbibes a tall glass of lone gunman Kool Aid.* [JFKFACTS](http://jfkfacts.org/assassination/eustace-tilley-theory-of-jfks-assassination/)
>
> *A partisan of modern dance, Miss Rambert acquired a love of classical ballet during her association with Diaghilev, and her respect for both dance forms helped shape her own career as a ballet director.* [The New York Times](http://www.nytimes.com/1982/06/14/obituaries/marie-rambert-94-a-leader-in-ballet.html)